# Volunteer to be bumped on Delta for upgrade when checking in online

Tags: delta-air-lines, upgrades

When one checks in online, Delta now asks how much money in travel vouchers it would take to get you to voluntarily give up your seat and be bumped to another flight. Suppose what I'd *really* like isn't travel vouchers but rather an upgrade to first class. Is it possible to request something like that? Even better, is it possible to say, I'll take either $X + an upgrade *or* $X + $Y?

Comment: You can offer whatever you want, and they can accept or reject your offer regardless ;).

Comment: The airline will normally fill first class by upgrading frequent fliers.  If they have seats available and haven't yet upgraded you, they probably haven't yet reached the point where the compensation for economy fliers is more costly than upgrading them.  But you can always ask.

Comment: @bliu how do I make that offer. There's no button for "upgrade" on the bidding page.

Comment: @Daniel Apologies, I assumed the person in question is already at the counter having access to a physical person. That would be a totally different question.

Comment: @phoog I think the OP means to get a first class seat on a later flight instead of an economy seat plus vouchers. I know most airlines can put you into premium economy.

Comment: Lovely idea, I will most definitely do this in the future: tell the gate agent I am filling to be moved to a later flight if I get a first class seat. On any flight longer than three hours this would be my preference compared to some monetary compensation.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no standard way to request that a portion of your compensation be a first class seat on the new flight you're bumped to.

*My speculation is:* requesting this would involve talking to the agent at the gate inside the airport while they find you a new flight. At that point you could offer to upgrade to first class if a seat is available. Doing this beforehand online is hard since the airline doesn't know which new flight you will agree to.

If you mean you want to be placed in first class on your **current** flight instead of being bumped to another flight, I believe that can't happen because your current flight is already 100% full.

Comment: I believe the question is describing a situation where you volunteer to be bumped from one flight in exchange for an upgrade on the next flight. In other words "I'll give up my seat on the noon flight in exchange for first class on the 4pm flight." In that case, the 4pm flight wouldn't be full, and it's possible that there's still room in first there. It sounds like you're describing a situation where someone volunteers for an upgrade on the same flight, which, sure, everyone would want that.

Comment: I believe you're correct... I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I have done exactly this. Once I got upgraded to first class, once to Premium Economy, and several times no upgrade at all.